# Jquery and Java Script does not work an all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

My java script and jquery doesn't work on all of my pages.
It works on the home page http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw  but not when I go to any other page like http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/#index.php etc.

I have a javascript function that loads content from another page into a div dynamically (the div is #ajax) and only the scripts run on items within that div are not working. For example, you'll see the text resize tool when you visit the main page and it works just fine, but when you click on another main tab, it's completely disabled. I think the ajax is causing the elements to become disabled because they only load on document.ready. What other approach can I take to keep these scripts working?

Comment: Please describe the actual problem.  The JavaScript **seems** to be working (somewhat) on all pages.  Secondly, you should see your home page in Safari... the main image is loading down the side of the page in slices before popping in up top.  It's a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the .load() method looks wrong.  Refer to this:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Should be something like

```
$('#ajax').load(url, function() {
   //do hover binding
});
```

Comment: Also try to put it inside the ready scope:

    $(function() {

      //code goes here

    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#ajax').load()(function(){
```

**btn.js:1Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function**

```
$(".btn").hover(function(){     
    $('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v',$(this).parent()).addClass("hvr");    
},     
function(){    
    $('.end-rght-h, .end-rght-v').removeClass("hvr");     
});
});
```

Something is breaking on that load somewhere..

Plus

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
doctors.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URL/images/headers/doctors.jpg 404 (Not Found)
barazi.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URLimages/pages/doctors/barazi.jpg 404 (Not Found)
berinstein.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URLimages/pages/doctors/berinstein.jpg 404 (Not Found)
byrnes.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URLimages/pages/doctors/byrnes.jpg 404 (Not Found)
deegan.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URLimages/pages/doctors/deegan.jpg 404 (Not Found)
desai.jpgGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/BASE_URLimages/pages/doctors/desai.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Base url? Something incorrect there.. You need to debug your site big time man.

Like Research link

```
research.phpGET http://www.steadfastdesignfirm.com/rgw/research.php 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: That is because the code expects the `load` method to return a function that can be called. Note the `$(...).load()(...);` syntax. The function should be a parameter to the `load` call, not a parameter to a call to the result of the `load` call.